# Search an hmap for a value

Tags: node.js, redis

If I have a redis hmap that looks like the following:

```
client.hset('test', 'one', 'aaa');
client.hset('test', 'two', 'bbb');
client.hset('test', 'three', 'ccc');
client.hset('test', 'four', 'ddd');
```

and I want to find if the map has a value like `ccc` whats the best way to do that?

I can call something like

```
 client.hgetall('test', function(err, obj){
     for(id in obj){
         if(obj[id] == 'ccc'){
             return id;
         }
     }
  });
```

But this seems very inefficient, is there a search or find method in redis that would produce nicer solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no built-in way to search by value. If you want to do it more efficient, you have to build an inverted index from value to key, e.g. *inverted-test*. Each time when you update the *test* hash, also update the inverted index.

```
HSET test one aaa
HSET inverted-test aaa one
```

**NOTE**

If in your original hash, multiple keys might have the same value. You might need to implement the inverted index with a `LIST`.

```
HSET test one aaa
LPUSH inverted-test:aaa one
HSET test two aaa
LPUSH inverted-test:aaa two
```

Comment: Thanks. This is the method I'm going to end up going with. Due to the nature of the keys and values there should not be a case where a key or value would repeat and if did that would mean an error already occurred much earlier in the application.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method like this:

```
client.hgetall('test', (err, obj) => {
    // in here we create an array of the object obj properties
    const keys = Object.keys(obj);
    // and now we iterate that array with the filter method
    const wantedValues = keys.filter(key => obj[key] === 'ccc');
    // wantedValues is now a array with the keys of the object obj that have the value ccc
});
```

Comment: While your answer does work I believe I'm still in the same boat when it comes to having call a `hgetall` and filtering though all the results. I was trying to take the load off the application and let redis deal with the logic of a search. Thanks anyway.